# Looping through JSON object with jquery not finidng indexes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

My PHP script is returning the below output according to Chrome console a json_encoded array:

```
{html: {achievements: [,…]}, total: 2, status: "success"}
    html: {achievements: [,…]}
        achievements: [,…]
            0: "<div class="achievement-wrapper" title="1,000 Alarms Reduced"><div class="achievement text-center" style="background-color: #e2d7eb;"><span class="achievement-text" style="color: #ffffff;"><i class="fa fa-bell-slash"></i></span></div></div>"
            1: "<div class="achievement-wrapper" title="2,000 Alarms Reduced"><div class="achievement text-center" style="background-color: #c5b0d7;"><span class="achievement-text" style="color: #ffffff;"><i class="fa fa-bell-slash"></i></span></div></div>"
    status: "success"
    total: 2
```

My jquery AJAX call with proper dataType of "json" looks like below:

```
$( json.html.achievements ).each( function() {
        console.log("Achievement: "+$(this).val() );
});
```

I'm having trouble looping through that json response to output the 2 different "achievements". Am I referencing the items incorrectly?

EDIT:

Not sure if it helps, but here is the "response" as shown in the Response tab of the console:

```
{"html":{"achievements":["<div class=\"achievement-wrapper\" title=\"1,000 Alarms Reduced\"><div class=\"achievement text-center\" style=\"background-color: #e2d7eb;\"><span class=\"achievement-text\" style=\"color: #ffffff;\"><i class=\"fa fa-bell-slash\"><\/i><\/span><\/div><\/div>","<div class=\"achievement-wrapper\" title=\"2,000 Alarms Reduced\"><div class=\"achievement text-center\" style=\"background-color: #c5b0d7;\"><span class=\"achievement-text\" style=\"color: #ffffff;\"><i class=\"fa fa-bell-slash\"><\/i><\/span><\/div><\/div>"]},"total":2,"status":"success"}
```

Comment: there is no html that would return `val()` what are you trying to do?

Comment: under the "achievements" node, there's 2 items. I'd like to output each one to the console separately in the loop (for now).

Comment: provide expected results

Comment: ultimately, i'll append the html from each item to a div's html() - $(myDiv).html( '<div class="achievement-wrapper" title="1,000 Alarms Reduced"><div class="achievement text-center" style="background-color: #e2d7eb;"><span class="achievement-text" style="color: #ffffff;"><i class="fa fa-bell-slash"></i></span></div></div>' );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$.each( json.html.achievements , function(i, val) {
  $('#myDiv').append(val[i]);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pf8v0nc/19/)

Here you can see the difference, since I added some text: https://jsfiddle.net/2pf8v0nc/20/

Comment: Any chance this site is live somewhere and we can test it?

Comment: Nice! If you get the chance, please mark this question as answered, if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
$.each( json.html.achievements , function(i, html) {
        console.log(html);
        $('#someDiv').append(html);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie! That worked - combination of the $.each change and the function arguments. One thing though, it's only outputting the 2nd item, not the first. Almost like it's not looping, or only seeing those 2 items as a single "index"?

Comment: That's copy and pasted directly from the Response body of the network tab.

Comment: note that there is conflict in data used in both answers. Demo i created uses the sample live data that is array of strings not objects